# Integrating a moving avatar for a bot using a GIF or any other method

Tags: android, android-animation, augmented-reality, chatbot, avatar

I want to introduce a anime character for a bot which can talk and show different action acording to situations. 
I was planning to implement it using different gif urls.Will there be any issue on implementing this way.
Is there any better Solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play GIF from image urls in Android's ImageView using `Glide`. The GIF will run smoothly. Another way of playing GIF is to use WebViews in Android

Comment: Will there be any issue during transition from one gif to another gif like white screen  on load

Comment: Well, most probably you will not face any issue if the file size is low. In case, you face issue like white screen, you can prefetch images in cache them in memory to load them faster and smooth transition.